# Why docker ADD destroys folder structure?

Tags: docker

I have the following folder structure:

```
> tree -L 3

├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       ├── groovy
│       └── resources
```

I tried to build docker image containing those folders together with files using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jamesdbloom/docker-java8-maven

USER root

RUN mkdir src
ADD ./src/* ./src/
ADD pom.xm
```

However, the structure in docker image is different. Particularly, I can no longer find `main` and `test` folders.

```
$ tree -L 3
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── groovy
│   │   └── com
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   └── resources
│       ├── ext_sample_input.json
│       ├── hist_sample_input.json
│       └── sample_input.json
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Fixed by using `ADD ./src ./src/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

Change your ADD statement to:

```
ADD ./src ./src/
```

Comment: Additionally, the `COPY` command may be used and should respect the folder structure.

Comment: Right, `./src/*` pattern has matched directories like `main` and `test` and has copied only content under it. Thanks!